# 2D screen position from 3D position using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some 3D objects within a rotating parent object.

I'm adding a set of 2D "hotspots" which follow these object's screen position. I got this to successfully convert the child object's position to 2D:

```
        // HOTSPOTS //
        var v1,m1,p,hotspotX,hotspotY;

        v1 = new THREE.Vector3();
        m1 = new THREE.Matrix4();


        m1 = childObject.matrixWorld;
        v1.setFromMatrixPosition(m1);
        p = projector.projectVector(v1, camera1);

        hotspotX = (p.x + 1) / 2;
        hotspotY = (-p.y + 1) / 2;
```

The problem is that rather than using the child object's origin as the hotspot location, I'd like to set it relative of it, i.e the hotspot's y might be childObject.y-10. I think this needs to happen prior to converting to matrix. Is there a way to do the same as matrixWorld, but from a vector instead of an object?

I could just create extra empty objects for each hotspot and set their positions exactly where I want them, however seeing as the childObjects are already there I'd rather use those if I can. All previous examples I've found use functions which are now deprecated. Hope this makes sense, I'm new to matrices.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not add a `hotspot` as an `Object3D` child of your `childObject` and set `hotspot.position.y = - 10`;? Alternatively, you could just transform your child's geometry up 10 units so the local origin and hotspot coincide.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is what I've now done, just thought there might be a way to directly translate it without creating extra objects. But it's working well now.